# Find all indices of pattern in string?

Tags: scala, functional-programming

Here is the code I have which looks ugly because it uses two vars.

```
  def patternMatching(pattern: String, genome: String): List[Int] = {
    assert(pattern.length < genome.length)
    var curr = 0
    var r = List[Int]()
    while (curr != -1) {
      curr = genome.indexOf(pattern, curr)
      if (curr != -1) {
        r ::= curr
        curr += 1
      }
    }
    r.reverse
  }
```

How do you write this in a functional way?

Comment: can you give us an exemple of input parameters and expected output ?

Comment: By the way, Scala has a built-in regex.

Comment: Yeah, you could make a REGEX and then use the method "findAllIn"

Comment: regex is a soln. I'm basically seeing how to go about writing a function with simple language constructs in a functional way. IndexOf is easy to understand how it works. Often times, using one or more vars in these cases gives a quick soln. And here's a test case: assert(patternMatching("ATAT", "GATATATGCATATACTT") == List(1,3,9))

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's quite straigthforward :

```
0.until(genome.length).filter(genome.startsWith(pattern, _))
```

Comment: Simple. Clever.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `unfold` method from [`scalaz`](https://github.com/scalaz/scalaz) like this:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

def patternIndexes(pattern: String, genome: String) = unfold(0){
  genome.indexOf(pattern, _) match {
    case -1 => None
    case n => (n, n+1).some
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
scala> patternIndexes("a", "aba").toList
res0: List[Int] = List(0, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler idiomatic Scala solution that does not require trying to explicitly apply a pattern at every location or using 3rd party library:

```
def patternMatching(pattern: String, genome: String): List[Int] =
  pattern.r.findAllMatchIn(genome).map(_.start).toList
```

Answer (score 0):

If you require to know also the ending position of the index you could use:

```
def patternMatchingIndex(pattern: Regex, text: String): List[(Int, Int)] =
  pattern.findAllMatchIn(text).map(index => (index.start, index.end)).toList
```